# Highcharts: How to add a table of values with scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is one of my failed attempts:

http://jsfiddle.net/mm484L57/

Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

```
// user options
var tableTop = 310,
    colWidth = 100,
    tableLeft = 20,
    rowHeight = 20,
    cellPadding = 2.5,
    valueDecimals = 1,
    valueSuffix = ' °C';

// internal variables
var chart = this,
    series = chart.series,
    renderer = chart.renderer,
    cellLeft = tableLeft;

// draw category labels
$.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function(i, name) {
    renderer.text(
        name, 
        cellLeft + cellPadding, 
        tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
    )
    .css({
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    })       
    .add();
});

$.each(series, function(i, serie) {
    cellLeft += colWidth;

    // Apply the cell text
    renderer.text(
            serie.name,
            cellLeft - cellPadding + colWidth, 
            tableTop + rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .attr({
            align: 'right'
        })
        .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        })
        .add();

    $.each(serie.data, function(row, point) {

        // Apply the cell text
        renderer.text(
                Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
            )
            .attr({
                align: 'right'
            })
            .add();

        // horizontal lines
        if (row == 0) {
            Highcharts.tableLine( // top
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + cellPadding
            );
            Highcharts.tableLine( // bottom
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }
        // horizontal line
        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding
        );

    });

    // vertical lines        
    if (i == 0) { // left table border  
        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );
    }

    Highcharts.tableLine(
        renderer,
        cellLeft, 
        tableTop + cellPadding,
        cellLeft, 
        tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
    );

    if (i == series.length - 1) { // right table border    

        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );
    }

});
```

The first part of the code is to create the table and the second is the chart.

The idea is that you can display the entire table of values although the graphics have a lot of values.

I tried to integrate the scrollbar of Highstock but not recognized as part of the graph too.

I think taht the main problem is that is not integrated in the DOM Highcharts but being integrated graphics not know how to format it with jQuery.

Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure if drawing big table with data in Highcharts charts is the best idea. If you will have big amounts of data, it will be problematic for your performance. Maybe you can make custom table below your chart instead?

Comment: Hi can you give me a link about this?

Comment: Of course, look at this plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data It will give you possibility to export data from your chart to table or CSV.