# How to modify data-table columns with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, datatable

Here is the fiddle I'm referring http://jsfiddle.net/mm484L57/

```
Highcharts.tableLine = function (renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    renderer.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2]).attr({
        'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 5
    }).add();
};
```

I would like to get the legend on the table to be in rows rather in column, 
it must be vice versa. Note: I'm referring to the data-table shown there. In 
simple, City names(Tokyo, New York, Berlin, London) must be row wise and the 
months should be column wise.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is official demo code taken from here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/b32bf4b8847de89c08de53cf1b11624fc9b56e42/samples/highcharts/studies/exporting-table/demo.js Have you tried to analyze and modify it?

Comment: May be. But I found the fiddle link somewhere in stack overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434666/highcharts-how-to-add-a-table-of-values-with-scrollbar
I found it from here.

Comment: Yes I tried but could n't get the desired result I want.

Comment: Table drawing logic is based on three loops: `chart.xAxis[0].categories.forEach`, `series.forEach` and `serie.data.forEach`. Which part of the code you don't understand? Could you provide what you've done so far?